# Highchartjs change based on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, highcharts

I try highchart to build a chart. and I have a radio button to select data.

So, how to change data on highchart based on click at radio button.

for example :

my radio button

- label-data-1
- label-data-2
- label-data-3
- label-data-4

[EDITED]
and my highchart

[when select label-data-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDHL5.jpg)

[when select label-data-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl0T7.jpg)

[when select label-data-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvV6L.jpg)

[when select label-data-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQwEU.jpg)
etc..

so when I choose label-data-1, highchart point change to 11 March, when I choose label-data-2, highchart point to 12 March, when I choose label-data-3, highchart point to 13 marc, etc..

Comment: You can use either multiple charts with toggle hide and show or bind a chart dynamically.

Comment: but i want to set selected cursor on highchart based on radio button. see edited question for detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your radio button has a common class `str_rad` and name `radbutton` than you can bind an on-click event on the radio button.

**JQuery:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
label-data-1<input type="radio" class="str_rad" name="radbutton" value="label-data-1"><br/>
label-data-2<input type="radio" class="str_rad" name="radbutton" value="label-data-2"><br/>
label-data-3<input type="radio" class="str_rad" name="radbutton" value="label-data-3"><br/>
label-data-4<input type="radio" class="str_rad" name="radbutton" value="label-data-4"><br/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.str_rad').click(function() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        //#container is your chart container div
        //For Remove Chart Updated style.
        chart.series[0].data[0].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: '#7cb6ee',radius: 4,symbol: ''
                     }
          });
          chart.series[0].data[1].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: '#7cb6ee',radius: 4,symbol: ''
                     }
          });
          chart.series[0].data[2].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: '#7cb6ee',radius: 4,symbol: ''
                     }
          });
          chart.series[0].data[3].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: '#7cb6ee',radius: 4,symbol: ''
                     }
          });
        //For Chart Updated style .
        if($(this).val() == "label-data-1")
        {
          chart.series[0].data[0].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: 'red',
                radius: 8,symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'  
                // There you can use any of the following radius or symbol for your chart as per your need.
                     }
          });
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "label-data-2")
        {
           chart.series[0].data[1].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: 'red',
                radius: 8,symbol:'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
                     }
           });
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "label-data-3")
        {
          chart.series[0].data[2].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: 'red',
                radius: 8,
                symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
                     }
          });
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "label-data-4")
        {
           chart.series[0].data[3].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: 'red',
                radius:8,
                symbol:
              'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
                     }
           });
        }

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3g69ky0t/)

Comment: sorry but i got this error in console. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

Comment: Ensure jQuery is imported before highchart.js.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> should be before your highchart library.

Comment: thanks all. work like a charm. with little improvement. https://jsfiddle.net/teguh111/bqztvz0c/